# Shared preferences - Bundles intent

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, gettext, settext

I'am trying to put a shared preference in a bundle so i can use it in another class.

So for example I have a class that views the strings inside a shared preference.
Then i have another class which can edit the string.

In my main class where i have created the bundle:

```
  SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

      Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(),verification.class);

       i.putExtra("sharedpreferences", sharedpreferences);
```

The issue is with the putExtra. it works for normal strings but not for the bundles, any ideas, i think its something simple

Comment: Are these classes in the same application? If so, you can access the same SharedPreferences from any class in your app without sharing using an intent.

Answer (score 2):

Of course `Intent.putExtra(...)` **works with Bundles**:

```
Intent.putExtra(String name, Bundle value);
```

Anyways, **there is no need to pass** the `SharedPreferences` as a `Bundle` to the next Activity.
Simply retrieve the `SharedPreferences` from the next `Activity` itself.

Save stuff into the `SharedPreferences`:

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context);
Editor e = sp.edit();
e.putString("key", "value"); // save "value" to the SharedPreferences
e.commit();
```

Retrieve stuff from the `SharedPreferences`:

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context);
String s = sp.getString("key", null); // get "value" from the SharedPreferences
```

**This makes not that much sense**, but here is how to put a `String` from the `SharedPreferences` into an `Intent`:

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context);
Intent i = new Intent(Context, YourActivity.class);
i.putExtra("key", sp.getString("key", null));
```

Comment: please refer to my original question, Iam trying to use a string from shared preference

Comment: I just showed you how to retrieve a string from the shared prefs. Take a look at my code.